# regex matching whitespace characters and multiple optional patterns before start of text

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing strings containing code like the following. It can start with an empty lines followed by multiple optional patterns. These patterns can either be python-style inline comments (using a hash # character), or the command "!mycommand", and both must start at the beginning of a line. How can I write a regex matching up to the starting of the code?

```
mystring = """

# catch this comment
!mycommand
# catch this comment
#catch this comment too
!mycommand

# catch this comment
!mycommand
!mycommand

some code. match until the previous line
# do not catch this comment
!mycommand
# do not catch this comment
"""

import re
pattern = r'^\s*^#.*|!mycommand\s*'
m = re.search(pattern, mystring, re.MULTILINE)
mystring[m.start():m.end()]

mystring = 'code. do not match anything' + mystring
m = re.search(pattern, mystring, re.MULTILINE)
```

I want the regex to match the string up to "some code. catch until the previous line". I tried different things but I am probably stuck with the two multiple patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern matches *one instance* of `# ...` or `!mycommand`. One way to solve this problem is to put all of them into one match, and use `re.search` to find the first match.

To do this, you need to repeat the part that matches `# ...` or `!mycommand` using `*`:

```
^\s*^(?:#.*\s*|!mycommand\s*)*
```

I have also changed `#.*` to `#.*\s*` so that it goes all the way to the next line where a non-whitespace is found.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kXR22A/1)

Responding to your comment:

> if the string begins with code, this regex should not match anything

You can try:

```
\A\s*^(?:#.*\s*|!mycommand\s*)+
```

I changed to `\A` so that it only matches the absolute start of the string, instead of start of line. I also changed the last `*` to `+` so at least one `# ...` or `!mycommand` has to be present.

Comment: two small problems: 1) if the string begins with code, this regex should not match anything; 2) the newline character before the code should be included in the match

Comment: When you say "begins with code", is the empty line at the start still there? The newline character before the code _is_ included in the match. @aless80

Comment: yes, you are right about point 1 and it is what i need. now let me fix point two. adding a \s* does not help

Comment: @aless80 See the edit. Did I understand correctly? If I misunderstood, and the answer to my previous comment were actually "no", change the _first_ `*` to `+`, rather than the last `*`.

Comment: The edit on the absolute start \A is a good one, but I do not want the last +. At that point what is missing is to catch any newline/space characters just before the code line, which in my example is "some code. match until the previous line"

Comment: @aless80 [It does match new lines just before the code](https://imgur.com/w6hz61W). See the "enter" symbol after "hello"? Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217089/discussion-between-aless80-and-sweeper).

Answer (score 2):

Without the need of *re.MULTILINE* you could repeatedly match 0+ whitespace chars before and after the match

```
^(?:\s*(?:#.*|!mycommand\s*))+\s*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mxOoEH/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ma4EWs)

For example

```
import re
m = re.search(r'^(?:\s*(?:#.*|!mycommand\s*))+\s*', mystring)
print(m.group())
```

Answer (score 1):

**Matching and returning the comments at the start of the string**

No need for a regex, read and append the lines to list until a line that does not start with `!` or `#` occurs and ignore all blank lines:

```
mystring = "YOUR_STRING_HERE"

results = []
for line in mystring.splitlines():
  if not line.strip():                                      # Skip blank lines
    continue
  if not line.startswith('#') and not line.startswith('!'): # Reject if does not start with ! or #
    break
  else:
    results.append(line)                                    # Append comment

print(results)
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##hZCxbsMwDER3fQVjD7YXL90K9EuKDorN1EIlShDpFv56l1JcIEBSZCOO7w5Hpk2WSC/7HjaW7OgT3qBpGmNamKxMC8jiGKYYApKYU9jKaGl@vG/vNZAYb31Pg29ZjgGVmXGEUE0rifNqRUgZv11cGbwj1NA5AkV5Wvp/rF6dkVcvrE94/zCXmGs6OIK/94ycvJOicj@8GgB3qYFFGQuSrjJornalFe8Ym4V/nCx913YDaK3Hy1N3BJ0z2i@d0DNelaPlaFNCmvtiHYxJ2k/6YzdUcN9/AQ). Results:

```
['# catch this comment', '!mycommand', '# catch this comment', '#catch this comment too', '!mycommand', '# catch this comment', '!mycommand', '!mycommand']
```

**Removing the comments at the start of the string**

```
results = []
flag = False
for line in mystring.splitlines():
  if not flag and not line.strip():
    continue
  if not flag and not line.startswith('#') and not line.startswith('!'):
    flag = True
  if flag:
    results.append(line)

print("\n".join(results))
```

Output:

```
some code. match until the previous line
# do not catch this comment
!mycommand
# do not catch this comment
```

See [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##hVC9bsQgDN55Ch8ZEhaWbpW69gm6tR1Q4jRUYBA4rfL0KXA56aT2ehv4@/PnuPES6GHf/ZY5WfqAJ5BSCtHBaHhcgBebYQzeI7E4@a0@DU1/493vGXAI17q7xtfcHDwWzoQafBOtxNYVKUJM@GXDmsFZwmI6BaDAd5e@TWutE@bVcS5HeH0XszP1HM/GZRRzSC0KLMHlVjpHZ7lO86AeBYCdm3sTlrz2qbCu/HjmQEksLWjF/wUmcf62vAx916vb4Kk/XI9tX9LFuA7O0NFKmxiRpqF6KCFiqcCDfCOpP4Ol4WAp1TT7/gM).

**Regex approach**

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'^(?:(?:[!#].*)?\n)+', '', mystring))
```

If there are optional indenting spaces at the start of a line add `[^\S\n]*`:

```
print(re.sub(r'^(?:[^\S\n]*(?:[!#].*)?\n)+', '', mystring, count=1))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2nV1Km/1) and the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##hVDLCoNADLzvV0Q9@KgIpbeC@BE9VgWrS11wE9mNBb/erkJBaIuBQEhmhsmMM/eEl2XRs2Wj8Ak5@L4vRABtw20P3CsLLWktkYWn53VssPt9D753wER73qHwHmtJS4fpZAZ6I03IanBUCaORL0WThUGhdKIdARIfmv4P275WeiTDYKQYXRgcGZnZ6RGZsI6K670ubyVWyTp6QZUlcVFifApTCF1/AkydorOZn@NYgKtleQM). `count=1` will make sure we just remove the first match (you need no check all other lines).

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^\S\n]*(?:[!#].*)?\n)+` - 1 or more occurrences of

  - `[^\S\n]*` - optional horizontal whitespaces
  - `(?:[!#].*)?` - an optional sequence of

    - `[!#]` - `!` or `#`
    - `.*`  - the rest of the line
  - `\n` -  a newline char.

Comment: indeed it is probably a good idea to avoid regex. Let me think about it

Comment: I did not write that in my question, but my end goal is actually to have the code part of my string. In other words I want to remove the initial newlines, comments, and !mycommand. I edited your code so that result looks like the mystring (with \n or spaces), then I "substract" result from mystring. however I am not sure how robust this method will be

Comment: @aless80 So do you mean you need to remove all up to `some code. match until the previous line`?

Comment: @aless80 You may still get it without a regex, but it is up to you to choose the path.

Comment: The downside of your 2nd approach is that the for loop has to go through all the lines. In my approach I get the matching in a way similar to your first approach, then do mystring[len(result):]. However I think I am opting for the regex approach (hopefully more "reliable")

Comment: @aless80 Added a regex approach. I suggest you use `count=1` to only `re.sub` the matched text *once*. Note that `\A` anchor does not mean `re.sub` will stop checking the rest of the lines, it will go on. `\A` only means there will be no match. `count=1` guarantees that it will stop even looking for the matches after the first one is found.